# Show more/less with moveable divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code below that contains 2 list of Divs `Total Fruits and Random Fruits` with a `Show more button`  that collapses it. The problem is when i add in a value from `Random Fruits` to `Total Fruits` without clicking the `Show More button` the list will expand.

Is there anyway to make the height of my list not expand or decrease whenever i move the values back and forth? Is there any better method that i should use for my current situation? Because i feel that being able to move the value back and forth is causing alot of bugs for my current method.

Any Help / Suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

```js
var redpill = {};
var greenpill = {};
var randompill = {};


var key = "Red Fruits";
redpill[key] = ['Apple', 'Cherry', 'Strawberry', 'Pomegranate', 'Rassberry', 'Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew', 'Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew', 'Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew'];

var key2 = "Green Fruits";
greenpill[key2] = ['Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew', 'Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew', 'Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew'];

var key3 = "Random Fruits";
randompill[key3] = ['Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew', 'Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew', 'Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew', 'Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew', 'Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew', 'Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew'];

function redraw() {
  var combineString = '';
  $.each(redpill[key], function(index) {
    combineString += ('<div class="pilldiv redpill class">' + redpill[key][index] + '</div>');
  });
  $('.combineclass').html(combineString);

  $.each(greenpill[key2], function(index) {
    combineString += ('<div class="pilldiv greenpill class">' + greenpill[key2][index] + '</div>');
  });
  $('.combineclass').html(combineString);

  var randomString = '';
  $.each(randompill[key3], function(index) {
    randomString += ('<div class="pilldiv randompill class">' + randompill[key3][index] + '</div>');
  });
  $('.randomclass').html(randomString);
}

function listener() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", "#suggestid div", function() {
      data = this.innerHTML;
      $(".total_count_Green_Fruits").html(key2 + ': ' + greenpill[key2].length);
      var element = $(this).detach();
      $('#currentid').prepend('<div class="new-green-fruit pilldiv class ">' + element.html() + '</div>');
    });
  });

  $('body').on('click', 'div.new-green-fruit', function() {
    data2 = this.innerHTML;
    $(this).detach();
    var element2 = $(this).detach();
    $('#suggestid').prepend('<div class="pilldiv randompill class" >' + element2.html() + '</div>');
  });
}
redraw();
listener();

$('#suggestid,#currentid').find('div:gt(15)').hide();
$(".button1").on("click", function() {
  $('#suggestid,#currentid').find('div:gt(15)').toggle();
});

function change() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("button1");
  if (elem.value == "Show Less") elem.value = "Show More";
  else elem.value = "Show Less";
}
```

```css
.pilldiv {
  padding: 8px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  color: Black;
  margin: 2px;
}

.randompill:after {
  content: "\002B";
  float: left;
  width: 16px;
}

.new-green-fruit:after {
  content: "\292B";
  float: left;
  width: 16px;
}

.redpill {
  background-color: Pink;
  cursor: default;
}

.greenpill {
  background-color: SpringGreen;
  cursor: default;
}

.randompill {
  background-color: LightBlue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.class {
  font-family: Open Sans;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrappingflexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.top {
  margin-bottom: 20px
}

h3 {
  font-weight: normal;
}

.panel {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 85%;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.new-green-fruit {
  background-color: LightBlue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.top {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.show-button {
  position: relative;
  left: 87%;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  background: none;
  text-decoration: underline;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <div style="float:left;width:calc(50% - 5px); background-color:#f2f2f2;">
    <h3 class="class center">Total Fruits</h3>
    <div id="currentid" class="combineclass wrappingflexbox top"></div>
  </div>

  <div style="float:right;width:calc(50% - 5px); background-color:#f2f2f2;">
    <h3 class="class center">Random Fruits</h3>
    <div id="suggestid" class="randomclass wrappingflexbox top"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<input onclick="change()" class="button1 show-button" type="button" value="Show More" id="button1" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is fixed `height` and `overflow-y` an option?

Comment: @KiranPaulVJ Sorry what do you mean?

Comment: What is meant is `#currentid {
  height:200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}` . Does this work for you?

Comment: @KiranPaulVJ Erm not really i dont want to add a scroll bar

Comment: If you don't want a scrollbar to appear, how is a user meant to see/access the items that were added if you also don't want to increase the container height? Do you want to combine a fixed height with `overflow-y: hidden`?

Comment: @Stevangelista By clicking the show more button. So if the user never press the show more button before adding in the value. The values will just move inside without the height increasing unless they press the show more button